# c++ Troubles with inherited class

Tags: c++

I'm completely new to C++, so please give me advice.

I have the following base class:

```
class IMatriz {
    int **m;
    int numRows;
    int numColumns;
public:
    IMatriz() {
        numRows = 0;
        numColumns = 0;
        m = NULL;
    }
    IMatriz(int r, int c) {
        numRows = r;
        numColumns = c;
        m = new int* [numRows];
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            m[i] = new int [numColumns];
        }
    }
    virtual void setSize(int r, int c) = 0;
    virtual void setValue(int row, int col, int val) = 0;
    virtual int getValue(int row, int col) = 0;
    virtual int getNumRows() = 0;
    virtual int getNumColumns() = 0;
    virtual void mult(IMatriz a, IMatriz b) = 0;
    virtual void print(void) = 0;
};
```

I'm wondering how to declare the inherited class.

I'm having problems with IMatriz().  The compiler sends me a message ISO C++ forbids declaration of `IMatriz' with no type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use indentation - It makes code more readable

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You're gonna have so much pain fixing the memory leaks. Use std::vector for the storage...

Comment: Show the exact compiler error message and the line of code it refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class IMatriz {
 protected:
  int **m;
  int numRows;
  int numColumns;
 public:
 IMatriz() {
    numRows = 0;
    numColumns = 0;
    m = NULL;
 }
 IMatriz(int r, int c) {
    numRows = r;
    numColumns = c;
    m = new int* [numRows];
    for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++)
      m[i] = new int [numColumns];
  }

virtual void setSize(int r, int c) = 0;
virtual void setValue(int row, int col, int val) { m[row][col] = val; }
virtual int getValue(int row, int col){ return m[row][col]; }
        int getNumRows(){ return numRows;}
        int getNumColumns(){ return numColumns; }
virtual void mult(IMatriz* a, IMatriz* b) = 0;
virtual void print(void) = 0;
};

class Child: public IMatriz{
 public:
   Child():IMatriz(){}
   Child(int row, int col):IMatriz(row, col){}
 };
```

1. Compilation error is because any class with pure virtual function cannot be instantiated directly. it must be through the pointer. so mult() definition is changed now.
2. In the derived class you should provide definition for the pure virtual functions otherwise although a child class it will still be an abstract class just like IMatriz i.e. cannot hav a regular variable, only pointer to it

Comment: Hi there. Really thanks I have to write the main like this      main()
{

   Matriz m;
   Matriz a(3,2);
   Matriz b(2,3);                                                                Is this is gonna work ?

Comment: yes but your IMatriz class is abstract.i.e. you cannot instantiate unless you remove pure virtual functions (virtual blah Blah()=0;) or implement them there or in some base class. If you choose to implement them in a child class then you can instantiate the variables of the child class. Also, if my answer has helped you, you can mark it as best answer but its your choice

Comment: Of course you are helping me a lot. im really aprecciate it. thanks a lot. and your answer is the best ,,,, now im getting it. but i have a problem with this     int IMatriz::numRows is private    you have an idea ?

Comment: right before the line int ** m; add the following **protected:** and all your members will be accessible in the derived classes

Comment: thanks the setSize functions it is like this                       void setSize(int r, int c){   
   numRows = r;
   numColumns = c;
}   is this right ?

Comment: how can i access the numRows for a fuction derived. for example virtual int getNumRows() = 0;   writing sin the main cout << "Rows: " << a.getNumRows();

Comment: I just changed the code in the answer. please see the answer. As for the setSize() yes you are correct

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. but I have to write all the methods in the child class

Comment: when i write the function mult i have and error  void Matriz::Mult(Matriz a, Matriz b);
cannot declare parameter `a' to be of type `Matriz'    This on the child class